# preg_match_all between backslash

Tags: php, preg-match

trying to extract data between two backslashes

read that a literal backslash must be 4...
Why 4 Backslashes?
Yes, it seems crazy to have to use 4 backslashes just to match one literal backslash!

but not working:

```
preg_match_all("/imgurl75/\\\/(.*?)/\\\//is", $data, $matches);
```

trying to extract data between both backslahs \  imgurl75\http://www.example.com/dir/dir/img.ext\

Comment: You have to escape the slashes or use another delimiter.

Comment: Please show us an sample input string and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("#imgurl75\\\\(.*)\\\\#", $data, $matches);
```